# Use Create ML object detection model in swift

Tags: swift, object-detection, createml

Hello I have created an object detection model in create ML and imported it to my swift project but I can't figure out how to use it. Basically i'm just looking to give the model an input and then receive an output. I have opened the Ml model prediction tab and found the input and output variabels but i don't know how to implement it code wise. I have searched on the internet for an answer and found multiple code snippets for running ml models but I can't get them to work.

This is the ML Model:
[ML Model predictions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwoXs.png)

This is the code I have tried:

```
let model = TestObjectModel()

guard let modelOutput = try? model.prediction(imagePath: "images_(2)" as! CVPixelBuffer, iouThreshold: 0.5, confidenceThreshold: 0.5) else {
    fatalError("Unexpected runtime error.")
}

print(modelOutput)
```

When running the code i get this error:

```
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x106c345c0).
The process has been left at the point where it was interrupted, use "thread return -x" to return to the state before expression evaluation.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok first to all you have to decide which type of Input you have declared.You can see it, when you click on your model in the project navigator.

For example :

```
let mlArray = try? MLMultiArray(shape: [1024],dataType: MLMultiArrayDataType.float32)
```

mlArray![index] = x --> giving your array some data

```
let input = TestObjectModel(input: mlArray!)
       do {

                  let options = MLPredictionOptions.init()
                  options.usesCPUOnly = true
                  let prediction = try? self. TestObjectModel.prediction(input: input, options: options)
```

--> now you can use prediction which is your output

```
                   } catch let err {
                       fatalError(err.localizedDescription) // Error computing NN outputs error
                   }
```

Another example for image as input for your model :

```
do {
    if let resizedImage = resize(image: image, newSize: CGSize(width: 416, height: 416)), let pixelBuffer = resizedImage.toCVPixelBuffer() {
        let prediction = try model.prediction(image: pixelBuffer)
        let value = prediction.output[0].intValue
        print(value)
    }
} catch {
    print("Error while doing predictions: \(error)")
}


func resize(image: UIImage, newSize: CGSize) -> UIImage? {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 0.0)
    image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height))
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return newImage
}
extension UIImage {
    func toCVPixelBuffer() -> CVPixelBuffer? {
        let attrs = [kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey: kCFBooleanTrue, kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey: kCFBooleanTrue] as CFDictionary
        var pixelBuffer : CVPixelBuffer?
        let status = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, Int(self.size.width), Int(self.size.height), kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB, attrs, &pixelBuffer)
        guard (status == kCVReturnSuccess) else {
            return nil
        }

        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer!, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))
        let pixelData = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer!)

        let rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        let context = CGContext(data: pixelData, width: Int(self.size.width), height: Int(self.size.height), bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(pixelBuffer!), space: rgbColorSpace, bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.noneSkipFirst.rawValue)

        context?.translateBy(x: 0, y: self.size.height)
        context?.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)

        UIGraphicsPushContext(context!)
        self.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height))
        UIGraphicsPopContext()
        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer!, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))

        return pixelBuffer
    }
}
```

Comment: When running this line of code: "let input = TestObjectModel(input: mlArray!)" i get error "Argument passed to call that takes no arguments". Do you know why this happens?

Comment: yes thats why i said you have to checkout your ML Object and check which type of Input you have set. I give you just an example. Can you edit your question and show us the model ?

Comment: I have now added a picture of the ml model input and outputs